# Virtual console not reading ~/.bashrc

Tags: bashrc, virtual-console

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, and have set up some custom functions in `~/.bashrc`.

The custom functions work fine when I open a terminal within the GNOME environment.

When I switch over to a virtual console (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), I don't get those functions.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` to include the line:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks, putting on ~/.bash_profile works. But it doesn't work when I put on ~/.profile. Do you have any idea why it's not reading up `~/.profile` ?

Comment: Read the bash man page (section about start-up files): if .bash_profile exists, bash will use it and ignore .profile.

Answer (score 0):

For more information about config files used by BASH please check below links

1. [Bash's behaviour](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour)
2. [The Bash Shell Startup Files](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html)
3. [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)